# Java - how can we get the selected or active frame (getSelectedFrame()) and passe it to JDialog()?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a mainFrame with a custom class loader. My loader is loading Pannels in the mainFrame as needed. In one of the pannel i have a JDialog. I want the JDialog box to blocks all windows from the application.

in the pannel i would like to do somting like this.

```
myDialog = new JDialog(getSelectedFrame(),"",Dialog.ModalityType...);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont' need it.  If you want to parent the dialog to a frame, dialog, or whatever you can simply call getTopLevelAncestor() on the component that is instantiating the JDialog.  That makes knowing the frame irrelevant which helps ensure the person calling or reusing code can use it on any component: frame, another dialog, window, etc.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getTopLevelAncestor()

For example:

```
class MySpecialPanel extends JPanel {

    public MySpecialPanel() {

        JButton button = new JButton( new AbstractAction("Show") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                JDialog dialog = new JDialog( (Window)getTopLevelAncestor(), "Some Title", Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL );
                dialog.add( new DialogPanel() );
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now by using MySpecialPanel.getTopLevelAncestor() the dialog you are creating doesn't need to know the exact component it is.  And the client using MySpecialPanel is free to put this panel into any container it desires be that a JFrame, another JDialog, or whatever.

Comment: JDialog dialog = new JDialog( getTopLevelAncestor(), true ); is returning this error "No suitable constructor found for JDialog(Java.awt.container, boolean)...". No matter how i get the parent, i get the same error.

Comment: Modified the code so it would compile, however, it's really for illustrative purposes rather than meant as something to copy exactly.

Comment: getTopLevelAncestor() - Didn't know about that. Very useful, though. Thanks my friend!